# HttpClient.PostAsync causes infinite Loop when calling at Page_Load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this Web Api call in my code behind. This is for my Single-Sign-On using Windows credential from our AD. What it did is just call the Web Api and check if the User is Authenticated and have access to the App.

I successfully call my Web Api using `HttpClient.PostAsync` but I'm wondering why it called several times in my `Page_Load`?

Please see below my `Page_Load` how I call the Web Api:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            var languages = Language.Enabled().OrderByDescending(x => x.IsDefault);
            var selected = languages.Where(x => x.Code == HSESA.Library.Helpers.Context.PublicLanguage().Code).Select(x => x.Code).FirstOrDefault();

            Test();
        }
    }
```

And here is the `Test()` method and how I initialized `HttpClient`:

```
 private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

 protected void Test()
    {

        string user = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        string FromUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

        #region Old Code
        var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Login", user));
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("FromUrl", FromUrl));
        System.Net.Http.HttpContent content = new System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);

        string url = "http://localhost:1899";
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var response = client.PostAsync("/api/login/checkLogin", content).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            LoginItemViewModel data = null;
            string responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject json = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(responseString);
            data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginItemViewModel>(responseString);
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Thanks in advance to someone that can help me with my problem.

Comment: @Igor I don't think that's it. The URL being called by the HttpClient is "/api/login/checkLogin". By convention in an MVC/WebAPI hybrid app this cannot point to a page, only to an API endpoint. So I doubt it's a recursion problem. Also the code in `Page_Load` will not execute during a POST request, due to the `if` statement.

Comment: @ADyson - you are correct.

Comment: @ADyson - yes, it point to the WebApi but not to a page. I just called this Api to process the authentication of the users credential which in this case is base on Windows Authentication. And for the `If` statement it successfully trigger the `Test()` method but my problem is that it always PostBack and I'm guessing this is because of the `PostAsync` but just my guess.

Comment: Sorry my comment is a bit out of context now Igor has deleted his original. I wasn't talking about your API call posting back, I was talking about your page. Igor thought that maybe you were getting this problem because the HttpClient was calling your webpage again, so you'd have an infinite loop. But I don't think that's true.

Comment: Without seeing some other code it's hard to know what's causing the issue. That code, on its own, should just run once. Could something be on a timer to repeatedly call this page somehow?

Comment: Hi @ADyson. Thanks for your help but I already know what causes this infinite loop on my code. As I check further the application when run locally on my machine it loads 4 times or so as it process the displaying of Login page popup. This is only happening locally but when it was deployed to Test Environment the Login popup only shows as soon as the application start. So, maybe this causes the infinite loop when calling the method.